# usercontrol adding another usercontrol programmatically in design time

Tags: winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a usercontrol (UC1) that changes aspect at design time according to what the user wants to show.

- A regular button that pops a window with usercontrol UC2 (the window is only shown at runtime)
- The UC2 directly hosted in UC1 (the regular button is then not shown)

Since I want to use the same UC2 instance in both situation, I just transfer ownership between UC1 and the form.

```
public UC1 ()
{
    _uc2 = new UC2 ();
}

public bool DisplayModeSimple
{
    get { return _displayModeSimple; }
    set
    {
        _displayModeSimple = value;
        if (_displayModeSimple)
        {
            // ... Verify if _uc2 is already in Controls...
            Controls.Remove (_uc2);
            uiButton.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // ... Verify that _uc2 is not in Controls ...
            Controls.Add (_uc2);
            uiButton.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

private void HandleButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Not called if DisplayModeSimple=false since button is hidden...
    using (var form = new PopupForm (_uc2))
    {
        form.ShowDialog (this);
    }
}
```

Works fine in both design and runtime mode.

In design mode if I change the display mode UC1 behaves correctly.

However, controls that are on UC2 can be clicked like if it was runtime.
If I then close the form hosting UC1 and reopen it everything is back to normal, i.e., I cannot "click" on any controls in UC2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first UserControl is hosted on VS, so it knows to be in design mode. The second UserControl is hosted in the first UserControl, so as its host is not a Designer, it thinks to be in a normal container and behaves accordingly. How to solve that is a bit tricky, as there isn't asimple solution AFAIK. [Here](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/identifying-run-time-and-design-mode.html) you can find some workarounds. Another could be to test Site.DesignMode recursively, but it depends on the level of depth of your controls.

Comment: Ok, I already know about testing design mode but it doesn't help since there's no place I could test this flag and force UC2 to be in "design mode". Furthermore, UC1 (with UC2 displayed) behaves normally upon the hosting form being displayed in the designer.